# Print Graphics Between Two Points In Assembly (MASM)

Tags: assembly, graphics, line, masm, points

I am trying to write a macro in MASM which enables me to display a graphic line from one point to another but the following code i have written just goes x axis and then y axis and not a line between the two points.

```
printFrom macro color, from_x, from_y, to_x , to_y

    mov si, from_x
    mov di, from_y

    .while temp != 0
        mov ah, 0ch
        mov al, color
        mov cx, si
        mov dx, di
        int 10h

        .IF si < to_x && di < to_y
            inc si
            inc di
        .ELSEIF si < to_x
            inc si
        .ELSEIF di < to_y
            inc di
        .ELSE
            mov temp, 0
        .ENDIF
    .endw

    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0
    mov temp, 1

endm
```

Kindly help me in modifying this code.

Comment: I suggest that you read up on some line-drawing algrithm, such as [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: An algorithm that draws a line between any two points on the screen is not a good candidate to store in a macro! Use a subroutine / procedure instead. Unless of course you want to bloat your application...